# SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column ' ' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

This error has been driving me crazy for a few days now

this is one row of about 10 in a 1000+ row file that will not import to my table.

I have attempted to add all of the columns in the insert statement, I have attempted removing columns, I have copied into notepad to make sure there were not strange characters, I have checked line endings, tried replacing spaces, removing backticks and nothing

**Can Someone please point to a solution.**

to make this even stranger, Some of the lines when I run this from client and it outputs the error with the sql if I copy that output and paste it in a new window it will run fine. I have attempted running from multiple clients(adminer, dbeaver, mysqlworkbench and phpmysql) and It returns the same errors in the same locations

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx_projects` (
  `id` int(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL ,
  `status` int(3) unsigned zerofill NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gp_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_type` varchar(15) DEFAULT 'SFH',
  `project_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `master_plan_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `client_id` int(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `kml_info` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `closeout_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=922 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Insert Statement**

```
INSERT INTO `xxx_projects`
(`id`, `status`, `name`, `project_type_id`, `client_id`, `city_id`, `lat`, `lon`)
VALUES (563,0,'Santa Ana Collection',10,135,256,33.73369 , -117.92058 );
```

**The Error Message**

> SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column ' ' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved!

**Character 160 (non-breaking space) is the Culprit**

In my original source file the user had been copy/pasting into excel from web pages to grab the data

I failed to sanitize that correctly and ended up with non-breaking spaces in my sql instead of char 32.

To resolve this in the original excel file I used this
`SUBSTITUTE(JackedUpString,CHAR(160),CHAR(32))`

Hope this helps someone else Since I did not find anything in SO related to this one

*[This Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) was useful as well*

Comment: The moral of this story is never to trust User Input. Ever!

Comment: 5 years later and this lesson is still important, especially when I am the "user" to not trust :)

Answer (score 0):

You declared  your status row as int but you are trying to put a character in it. Note that '0' is a character and 0 is an integer. From my experience with mysql I think this is the problem . Hope this solves your issue. Also if I were you, I'd declare 'lat' and 'lon' as varchar.

Comment: in my real file i am passing the int 0 not a varchar '0' that was just remnants of one of my tests. i will modify the OP

Comment: Did you create the table in mysql console with the names of the rows enclosed in backticks?

Comment: Yes in some tests, but never with an issue. I actually solved this issue. i am going to post the answer shortly